# Crystal Reports Error in formula

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have a global variable which was declared in a formula in the Report Header section of my document.  I then try to reference that variable to use it in a for loop, and I get the error:

> A number, currency amount, boolean,
>   data, time, date-time, or string is
>   expected here.

What is wrong here and how can I correct?  Code follows:

Header Formula:

```
Global StringVar Array items;
redim items [1];

Global StringVar Array jobs;
redim jobs [1];

Global StringVar Array POs;
redim POs [1];

Global StringVar Array Qty;
redim Qty [1];

Global NumberVar numRecordsPrinted;
numRecordsPrinted := 0;

""
```

Detail Formula:

```
    Local NumberVar occurances;
    Local StringVar poTOuse;
    Local NumberVar i;

    if {%Line_PO_Test} <> ''
    and {PackingSlipHeader.CompanyCode} <> '10063'
    and {PackingSlipHeader.CompanyCode} <> '10017'
    then 
        //Count the number of occurances 
        For i := 0 To numRecordsPrinted Do       //Error on numRecordsPrinted
        (
            if items[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.DTSItemNumber}
                AND jobs[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.JobNumber}
                And Qty[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped}
                THEN
                    occurances := occurances + 1
        )

        //Use the # of occurances to get the right PO number
Select occurances 
        case 0: poTOuse := {@LinePOnum}
        case 1: poTOuse := {@Line_PO_3}
        case 2: poTOuse := {@Line_PO_2}

        default: poTOuse := "";


        //Save data into the array and increment for next time
        numRecordsPrinted := numRecordsPrinted + 1
        items[numRecordsPrinted] := {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.DTSItemNumber}
        jobs[numRecordsPrinted] := {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.JobNumber}
        Qty[numRecordsPrinted] :=   {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped}

    //Print to the report
    'PO#: ' + poTOuse;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crystal reports syntax, the variables have to be declared each time you use them.  I wasn't aware that I have to declare the variables both in the header formula, and the detail formula.  I made some other small syntax errors, but that was the main problem.

I didn't even consider this as a possibility because in most languages, declaring a variable more than once will cause the program to not even compile, let alone run.

Header Section

```
BeforeReadingRecords;

Global StringVar Array items;

Global StringVar Array jobs;

Global StringVar Array POs;

Global NumberVar Array Qty;

Global NumberVar numRecordsPrinted;

""
```

Detail Section

```
WhileReadingRecords;
Global StringVar Array items;

Global StringVar Array jobs;

Global StringVar Array POs;

Global NumberVar Array Qty;

Global NumberVar numRecordsPrinted;
Global NumberVar occurances;
occurances := 0;

Global StringVar poTOuse;
Global NumberVar i;

ReDim Preserve items[CDbl(Ubound(items) + 1)];
ReDim Preserve jobs[CDbl(Ubound(jobs) + 1)];
ReDim Preserve POs[CDbl(Ubound(POs) + 1)];
ReDim Preserve Qty[CDbl(Ubound(Qty) + 1)];

if {%Line_PO_Test} <> ""
and {PackingSlipHeader.CompanyCode} <> "10063"
and {PackingSlipHeader.CompanyCode} <> "10017"
then 
    //Count the number of occurances
    For i := 1 To (numRecordsPrinted + 1) Do
    (
        if items[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.DTSItemNumber}
            AND jobs[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.JobNumber}
            And Qty[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped}
            THEN
                occurances := occurances + 1
    );

    //Use the # of occurances to get the right PO number
    Select occurances 
        case 0: poTOuse := {%Line_PO_Test}
        case 1: poTOuse := {%Line_PO_3}
        case 2: poTOuse := {%Line_PO_2}

        default: poTOuse := "";

    //Save data into the array and increment for next time
    numRecordsPrinted := numRecordsPrinted + 1;
    items[numRecordsPrinted] := {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.DTSItemNumber};
    jobs[numRecordsPrinted] := {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.JobNumber};
    Qty[numRecordsPrinted] :=  {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped};

//Print to the report
if poTOuse <> "" THEN
'PO#: ' + poTOuse
ELSE
"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely this bit :

```
    Select occurances 
        case 0: poTOuse = LinePOnum
        case 1: poTOuse = Line_PO_3
        case 2: poTOuse = Line_PO_2

        default: poTOuse = "";
```

should be

```
    Select occurances 
        case 0: poTOuse := LinePOnum
        case 1: poTOuse := Line_PO_3
        case 2: poTOuse := Line_PO_2

        default: poTOuse := "";
```

Although it's not clear what LinePOnum, Line_PO_3 and Line_PO_2 are.

Comment: Yes, looks like your correct.  Those are other Crystal Report formulas, but I didn't reference them properly.  I'll correct this part and edit the question.  Any ideas on the error code?

Answer (score 1):

If you comment out the following section of code like so, do you still get an error?

```
For i := 0 To numRecordsPrinted Do       //Error on numRecordsPrinted
        (
//            if items[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.DTSItemNumber}
//                AND jobs[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.JobNumber}
//                And Qty[i] = {PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped}
//                THEN
                    occurances := occurances + 1
        )
```

If yes, do you still get the error when you comment out `occurances := occurances + 1`?

Since the arrays are StringVars, you *might* need to wrap your database fields with `cstr` like this:

```
(
        if items[i] = cstr({PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.DTSItemNumber})
            AND jobs[i] = cstr({PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.JobNumber})
            And Qty[i] = cstr({PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped})
            THEN
                occurances := occurances + 1
    )
```

If you want to remove the trailing decimals for the Quantity_Shipped, you can use `cstr({PS_DETAIL_FOR_PRINT.Quantity_Shipped}, "0")` instead.

Comment: None of these were the main problem, but since you took the time to look and investigate, you deserve the bounty.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue-- the " character in MS-Office is NOT the same thing as the MS-DOS " character. Save your formula in word as a strict MS-DOS .txt file and then copy-paste that into the CR formula editor. It's saved me before